Conjecture: The sum of the coefficients of terms in the $n$-th derivative of $\sec (x)$ is $n!$ (and another pattern)
Let $f^{(n)}$ stands for the $n$th derivative.
The conjectured pattern is:

The summation of coefficients of the terms of $(\sec {x})^{(n)}$ equals $n!$

For example:

$(\sec {x})^{(0)}=\sec (x)$, the summation is $0!=1$
$(\sec {x})^{(1)}=\sec (x) \tan (x)$ , the summation is $1!=1$
$(\sec {x})^{(2)}=\sec (x) \tan^{2} (x)+ \sec ^{3} (x)$ , the summation is $2!=2$
$(\sec {x})^{(3)}=\sec (x) \tan^{3} (x)+5\sec^{3} (x) \tan (x)$ , the summation is $3!=6$
$(\sec {x})^{(4)}=\sec (x) \tan^{4} (x)+5\sec^{5} (x)+18\sec^{3} (x) \tan^{2} (x)$ , the summation is $4!=24$
$(\sec {x})^{(5)}=\sec (x) \tan^{5} (x)+61\sec^{5} (x) \tan (x)+58\sec^{3} (x) \tan^{3} (x)$ , the summation is $5!=120$

Also, note another conjectured pattern:

For each term $\sec^{\ell}(x) \tan^{m} (x)$ in $(\sec {x})^{(n)}$, we have: $\ell+m=n+1$.

Do these patterns hold for all $n \in \{0,1,2,... \}$?
How to prove them?

What have you tried?

@mweiss I checked the pattern of $n!$ for many values, but I am not able of proving it, so I want hint from users here, just hints because I should learn actively not just take the answer from users here.

Have you tried induction?

@mweiss I don't think Induction work  for this problem, because we can prove base case, then assume the statement is true for $k$ but we can't using this to prove it is true for $k+1$.

Perhaps the general form of the product rule will be helpful here

Please specify that "the summation" should be from where the total powers of $\sec x$ and $\tan x$ are the same like $\sec x\tan^2x + \sec^3x$, not something else like $2\sec^3x - \sec x = 2\sec x \tan^2 x + \sec x$.

@peterwhy You just don't use identities like $\tan^{2} (x) = \sec^{2} (x) -1$ or any other identity, I mean that you just differentiate every time and collect the similar terms together, then when adding the coefficients in the $n$th derivative you get $n!$ .

You say, regarding induction, "but we can't using this [the induction hypothesis] to prove it is true for $k + 1$" -- what makes you so certain that this can't be done? It seems to me that this is precisely what you should be trying to do. If you've tried it, where did that effort fail?

@mweiss How could I assume the form of derivative for $k$th derivative when I want to use it to prove the summations of coefficients is $(k+1)!$ for the $k+1$th derivative, my problem is I need the exact form of $k$th derivative of  $\sec x$, so that I told you that Induction doesn't seem to work

You can assume as the induction hypothesis that $f^{(k)}(x) = \sum_{i=0}^{k+1} a_i \sec^i (x) \tan^{(k+1)-i} (x) $, where the coefficients $a_i$ sum to $k!$.  Then prove the corresponding statement, where $k$ is replaced with $k+1$.

As hinted in previous comments, you don't need the exact form of the derivative.

@mweiss I am thankful for your hint, I will use it now to solve the question.

Good observations about the patterns, by the way, which led you to a good conjecture.

The solution using user mweiss' hint and help:
By induction:
Base case:
$n=0$, the statement is clear.
Induction:
Assume the statement is true for $n=k$, so:
$\sec^{(k)} (x)=\sum_{i=0}^{k+1} a_{i} \sec^{i} (x) \tan^{k+1-i} (x)$ such that $\sum_{i=0}^{k+1} a_{i}=k!$.
Now, let's prove the statement for the $(k+1)$th derivative.
$\sec^{(k+1)} (x)=\sum_{i=0}^{k+1} (ia_{i} \sec^{i} (x) \tan^{k+2-i} (x)+ (k+1-i)a_{i} \sec^{i+2}(x)\tan^{k-i} (x) )$.
The summation of coefficients is $\sum_{i=0}^{k+1} (ia_{i}+(k+1-i)a_{i})=(k+1) \sum_{i=0}^{k+1} a_{i}=(k+1)k!=(k+1)!$.
